# Replace multiple regex matches with different strings

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to replace multiple regex matches with different text, just like that, but not working :/

This is my string:

```
str = [answers] => [{"pref1":0,"answerTime":800},{"pref2":0,"answerTime":800},{"pref3":0,"answerTime":800},{"pref4":0,"answerTime":800},{"pref5":0,"answerTime":800}]
```

I want to replace each answer time do a random time from an array list, like:

```
$time = array('"answerTime":1000,"','"answerTime":800,"','"answerTime":1200,"','"answerTime":1100,"','"answerTime":1500,"','"answerTime":900,"');
$rnd1 = $time[array_rand($time, 1)];
$rnd2 = $time[array_rand($time, 1)];
$rnd3 = $time[array_rand($time, 1)];
$rnd4 = $time[array_rand($time, 1)];
$rnd5 = $time[array_rand($time, 1)];
$replace = array($rnd1, $rnd2, $rnd3, $rnd4, $rnd5);
```

But everytime i the method below, all the results return me the same time:

```
$postpop = preg_replace('#"answerTime":(.*?),"#', array($replace), $reqpop);
```

Comment: What does $str look like? can you give us an example? Can you also give us an example input and example wrong output as long as what you were expecting.

Comment: Edited, hope its better

Comment: Why are there `#` characters in the regex if they aren't used in the string?

Comment: Also, your edit helps  a little.  But wee need more info, like what results are you getting? Are you getting an empty string? Is the function not running at all? Are you getting the same string you started out with? We need more info to diagnose the problem.

Comment: Its just an example.
For me, the regex is working
I just dont know this: how to replace the 5 matches i get with different values?
When i try to replace the matches with a simples value, like:

$postpop = preg_replace('#"answerTime":(.*?),"#', "something", $str);

it works.

Comment: Please do more to explain the task, provide data for all variables that are included, and provide a possible/expected output.  What is the whole `$str` value? Does it _need_ to be replaced or can it be overwritten entirely?  What does `$time` look like?

Comment: Edited
All i want to do is to replace the regex results i get (5 values), with different numbers (a,b,c,d,e)

Comment: Can you provide your strings, what you are trying, and what you want to accomplish?

Comment: Edited, hope its now easy to look.

Comment: Can you define what you want to replace? Your `.*?` is going to match all examples. You might be able to get away with a `str_replace`.

Comment: @JohnSnow your question is still not clear.  Can you please associate data with actual variable names?  i don't know what `str` is.  If it is an array it is unclear what its structure is.  Is it `$reqpop`?  Do we fetch `$reqpop` by calling `json_decode()` on `$reqpop['answers']`?  chris or I can help you if you clarify your question.  Show your desired result.

Comment: i want to replace all the values from str: (there are 5 of them, with the value "800")
but, i need them to be replaced each one with diferent values

Comment: Please show me some **usable** data to start from.  I need to get the syntax of your json string correct before I can move forward.  I don't know what `$reqpop` is  Using regex to modify a json string is a bad idea.  I will be converting to an array and modifying it then returning to json when done.

Comment: @mickmackusa hope its clear now
https://pastebin.com/6PudvvH1

Answer (score 1):

Judging by [your other SO account's question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45846803/edit-and-redirect-a-post-request-with-json) using my previous coding attempt with your sample `$_POST` data, this should be right for your task:

Method #1:  ([The non-regex / more stable way](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/60bb265c7aa7bef4a772833bca386b5acff99c11))

```
$_POST=[
    'authToken'=>'0a65e943412453ecec35c814',
    'sessionId'=>'431503466924',
    'answers' => '[{"Boost":false,"answerTime":1300,"id":3},{"Boost":false,"answerTime":800,"id":1},{"Boost":false,"answerTime":900,"id":3},{"Boost":false,"answerTime":1000,"id":1},{"Boost":false,"answerTime":1200,"id":1}]',
    'userId' =>'2235'
];

$time=[800,900,1000,1100,1200,1500];
$answers=json_decode($_POST['answers'],true);  // convert "answers" value to an array
foreach($answers as &$a){                      // iterate each subarray
    $a['answerTime']=$time[array_rand($time)]; // replace the previous answerTime value with a new random one
}
$_POST['answers']=json_encode($answers);       // apply updated & re-encoded "answers" string to $_POST
var_export($_POST);
```

Method #2: ([The regex / less stable way](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/bc72ced7b45143326398a2169aa66e9a1b266457))

```
$_POST=[
    'authToken'=>'0a65e943412453ecec35c814',
    'sessionId'=>'431503466924',
    'answers' => '[{"Boost":false,"answerTime":1300,"id":3},{"Boost":false,"answerTime":800,"id":1},{"Boost":false,"answerTime":900,"id":3},{"Boost":false,"answerTime":1000,"id":1},{"Boost":false,"answerTime":1200,"id":1}]',
    'userId' =>'2235'
];

$time=[800,900,1000,1100,1200,1500];
$_POST['answers']=preg_replace_callback('/answerTime":\K\d+/',function($m)use($time){return $time[array_rand($time)];},$_POST['answers']);
var_export($_POST);
```

The `\K` in the regex pattern says: "start the fullstring match from here", then it matches only the digits that follow `answerTime:`.

Possible output with either method:

```
array (
  'authToken' => '0a65e943412453ecec35c814',
  'sessionId' => '431503466924',
  'answers' => '[{"Boost":false,"answerTime":1200,"id":3},{"Boost":false,"answerTime":1000,"id":1},{"Boost":false,"answerTime":1500,"id":3},{"Boost":false,"answerTime":900,"id":1},{"Boost":false,"answerTime":800,"id":1}]',
  'userId' => '2235',
)
```

Comment: @JohnSnow Maybe it will be easier if you tell me what is not quite right with my variable names / data.  Once this is close to what you want, I can add the explanations (back in 10 minutes)

Comment: This is now up to date and should provide what you are looking for.